# HTML5: Real-time sound

Tags: html, html5-video, html5-audio

Can HTML5 (or anything in the browser) be used to transmit sound in real-time? Like Skype for example?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can play and possibly stream sound using the  tag from server to browser. You cannot access the computers microphone using html5. You will need flash or java for this.